# Can you save something in LocalStorage with a variable?

Tags: javascript, local-storage

So this is a quick question, but I was unable to find an answer anywhere.
I know to save things in localStorage you write like this:

```
localStorage.name = JSON.stringify("this has now been saved under name);
```

But I want to be able to change what it is saved under depening on a variable, like this:

```
const banana = potato
localStorage.banana = JSON.stringify("this has now been saved under potato");
```

Is this possible to do? :)
​​​​​​​

Comment: Can you clarify? Do you want to *remove* the previous key `name` and add `banana`?

Comment: Also, how does the determine what needs to be saved and how?

Comment: Sorry! I updated it now ^^

Comment: You don't need to stringify it is already a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Localstorage allows for the storage of key and value pairs where the value is a string.

If you are assigning to localstorage from reference to another variable, if it resolves to a string then that will work:

```
const potato = "potato";
const banana = potato;
localStorage.setItem(banana, "this has now been saved under potato");
```

Otherwise you will need to stringify the value of the variable first.

https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_webstorage.asp

Comment: Thank you! :)
I was just what I needed ^^

Answer (score 1):

You can set variables in localStorage with dynamic keys like

```
const banana = potato
localStorage.setItem(banana, "this has now been saved under potato")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add data to your localstorage. You have an key and a value,both need to be strings.

```
window.localStorage.setItem('myCat', 'Tom');
```

and you can get it like this:

```
window.localStorage.getItem("myCat");
```

To store an variable, array, object etc. you will need to convert it to an string first like this for example:

```
let arr = [1, 2, 3];
//you need to convert this array to an string.
let arr_string = JSON.stringify(arr);

//now you can store it in your local storage

window.localStorage.setItem("myArray", arr_string);

//to get the array you will need to parse it back from string to array.

let arr_string = window.localStorage.getItem("myArray");
let arr = JSON.parse(arr_string);

console.log(arr); // output: [1, 2, 3]
```